# simpliest increase - decrease value options in select area using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

at the beginning I want to say that I am a novice in jquery. 
I want to create an  field, which will contain years. Also I want to make two arrows left, and right. After clicked they should change values in my select field - in increasing and decreasing way. Whenever the text which is inside each option.

My current code prepared just to show You this looks like:

**HTML**

```
    <a href="#" title="">
        <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_48px-128.png" alt="" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" title="">
        <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_48px-128.png" alt="" />
    </a>

    <br />

    <select class="my-select">
        <option selected value="select">2015</option>
        <option>2014</option>
        <option>2013</option>
        <option>2012</option>
    </select>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.my-select {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-indent: 30px;
}
```

and the fiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/6uLxp1hx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Simple JQuery method to select the next value on button click and previous value on button click based on the current selected value.

[JSFillde](http://jsfiddle.net/6uLxp1hx/3/)

2. Added a second method to show and hide the values based on the value of the Option eq the first/last.

[JSFillde 2](http://jsfiddle.net/6uLxp1hx/5/)

3. Added a DMY generic version based on the request of the creator.
   HTML

   ```
   <a href="#" id="fieldBefore-Day" title="">
       <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_48px-128.png" alt="" />
   </a>
   <a href="#" id="fieldNext-Day" title="">
       <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_48px-128.png" alt="" />
   </a>

   <br />

   <select id="selection-Day" class="my-select">
       <option selected value="select">31</option>
       <option>30</option>
       <option>29</option>
       <option>28</option>
   </select>
   ```

   ```
   <a href="#" id="fieldBefore-Month" title="">
       <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_48px-128.png" alt="" />
   </a>
   <a href="#" id="fieldNext-Month" title="">
       <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_48px-128.png" alt="" />
   </a>

   <br />

   <select id="selection-Month" class="my-select">
       <option selected value="select">12</option>
       <option>11</option>
       <option>10</option>
       <option>9</option>
   </select>
   ```

   ```
   <a href="#" id="fieldBefore-Year" title="">
       <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_48px-128.png" alt="" />
   </a>
   <a href="#" id="fieldNext-Year" title="">
       <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_48px-128.png" alt="" />
   </a>

   <br />

   <select id="selection-Year" class="my-select">
       <option selected value="select">2015</option>
       <option>2014</option>
       <option>2013</option>
       <option>2012</option>
   </select>
   ```

JS

```
function main(value){
    if ( $('#selection-'+value+' option:first').val() == $('#selection-'+value+' option:selected').val() ){
     $('#fieldNext-'+value).hide();
     $('#fieldBefore-'+value).show();
    }else if($('#selection-'+value+' option:last').val() == $('#selection-'+value+' option:selected').val()){
     $('#fieldNext-'+value).show();
     $('#fieldBefore-'+value).hide();
    }else{
     $('#fieldNext-'+value).show();
     $('#fieldBefore-'+value).show();
    }
}

function prev(value){
    $('#selection-'+value+' option:selected').prev().attr('selected', 'selected'); 
    main(value);
}

function next(value){
    $('#selection-'+value+' option:selected').next().attr('selected', 'selected');
    main(value);

}



function generate(value){
    $(document).ready(main(value));
    $('#selection-'+value).on('change', function() {main(value)});
    $('#fieldNext-'+value).on('click', function() {prev(value)});
    $('#fieldBefore-'+value).on('click', function() {next(value)});
}

generate('Day');
generate('Month');
generate('Year');
```

[JSFillde 3](http://jsfiddle.net/6uLxp1hx/7/)

Comment: It breaks when you click next and the selected value is already the highest. Same with the lowest value and previous button

Comment: The before and after value was the wrong way round. I do not get it any JS error on IE 11 or Chrome. Also you could easily add a JS check to see if you were at the end or the start and hide the arrow as that is the method I would use.

Comment: Thank You, it works just great. I used example where the arrows disapears when there's nothing to prev/next. I have a question, what do I need to change to make it work multiple on my site. I want to make two selects, one with days, one with years. Is there some uniwersal way, or I have to duplicate existing jquery code and make changes ?

Comment: Had some free time, I added a final method to do this with a generic function call generate('Day');generate('Month');generate('Year');

Comment: Thank You Darren once more. I see You've made days evan - just for case hehe :) Many many thanks to You Sir! You saved my whole day of

Answer (score 2):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6uLxp1hx/6/) working code

```
$('#prev').click(function(){
    //$("#year option:selected").index();
 var current=$("#year option:selected").index();
    current--;
 var total=$("#year option").length;   
if(current>=0){
    $( "#year option" ).eq( current ).attr("selected","true");
}
});
$('#next').click(function(){
var current=$("#year option:selected").index();
    current++;
 var total=$("#year option").length;   
if(current<=total){
    $( "#year option" ).eq( current ).attr("selected","true");
}
});
```

Comment: Thank You for simple and short version of this.

Answer (score 1):

I edited your code. Check here [WORKING CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/c_psumit/6uLxp1hx/2/)

```
$('#prev').click(function(){
    $('#year').val($('#year').val()-1);
});
$('#next').click(function(){
    $('#year').val($('#year').val()+1);
});
```

Comment: This is not a good method of doing it as the option value could be something random and not an incrementable value. You are better using the .next and .prev method in JQuery

Comment: Thank You for trying to help :)